# DPDK basic HW requirement

Tags: dpdk

I am looking for the `DPDK + Vhost`. Do you know what is the minimum hw (like CPU, ram size etc) requirement for this activity. I am having the following combination :-

- Fedora Core 20 inside a virtual box
- 4GB given to Fedora

Idea is to have a VM inside this fedora which can use dpdk vhost to forward the packet.

Comment: I think I will give up on this as I haven't got any confirmation on this. In case if I want the same to do it on real hardware (like i5 or i7) I hope this is possible with 8G Ram

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is really nothing special about hardware requirement by DPDK. Most commonly, not having a NIC that is supported by DPDK could probably be the show stopper. 4G memory is definitely able to power it up (maybe you don't want to use 1G hugepage but 2M instead).